# C# temporary variable error

Tags: unity, c#

I get the following error when running the code below:

> Cannot modify a value type return value of
>   `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a
>   temporary variable

```
public void Hello () {

    transform.position.y -= 1;
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `x`, `y` and `z` are components of "transform.position", and you are not allowed to make changes to single components of properties. In other words, you can not directly assign a value to `transform.position.x`,`transform.position.y` or `transform.position.z` or similar things. You have to do the following:

```
mynewY = transform.position.y - 1;
transform.position.y = new Vector2(transform.position.x,mynewY);
```

or if you want to do it directly:

```
transform.position.y = new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y - 1);
```

In 3D cases, the solution is similar:

```
mynewY = transform.position.y - 1;
transform.position.y = new Vector2(transform.position.x,mynewY,ransform.position.z);
```

or if you want to do it directly:

```
transform.position.y = new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y - 1,ransform.position.z);
```

The same applies in almost all other situations when using C# in Unity.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change single coordinates of a Vector3 since it is immutable. Assign a new Vector3:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
                                 transform.position.y - 1,
                                 transform.position.z);
```

Note that the immutability of a class or struct is a design decision. Structs are not generally immutable. Immutability is realized by making all the properties readonly and making fields private. The initial values are usually passed as constructor parameters. Of course methods are not allowed to change the values.

Answer (score 2):

transform.position is a Vector3. You can find this information by going to the declaration of Vector3 via your IDE or looking up the member in Unity's documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html

Structs in C# are call-by-value, which means that you effectively get a copy of them when you get them and any changes to the values will be made on this "copy". You therefore can NOT change a structs values after it has been created.
You can read more on structs and their (often weird behavior) on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taef578.aspx

You assign a new instance of a Vector3 to the transform.position member as follows:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y -1, transform.position.z);
```